# changing heroku app name to custom domain issue

Tags: heroku, dns

I have read the article on heroku website for setting custom customs(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

I'am using namecheap domain service, here's a picture of how the cname record looks:

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPDzX.jpg)

Like the heroku custom domain article says I have to do the following:

```
 heroku domains:add www.ubbytech.com   -- which is the name of my domain i paid for
```

I entered the dns target in my advanced dns settings on namecheap dashboard.

Here's a picture of my terminal display output:

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chtqs.jpg)

What I'am doing wrong. I followed the article thoroughly; and I've even tried doing it via heroku account settings. Sometimes it would work for 10 seconds then stop working.

Comment: Looks like you've got this working now - DNS can take a while to propagate, I'm able to load your site without an issue...

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I tend to have a problem with being impatient lol. plus this my first time setting dns. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: @JohnBeynon I'm just curious about something. I just entered the url to my site and it works, but after 2-3 minutes I open it again and it shows the default page for namecheap sponsored listing page. Do you know why this is happening? or like you said....should I just wait couple of days? because I did just purchase the domain yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something not quite right with your DNS. Take a look at subsequent `dig` commands to inspect the records:

```
→ dig www.ubbytech.com
www.ubbytech.com.   1799    IN  CNAME   parkingpage.namecheap.com.
parkingpage.namecheap.com. 29   IN  A   198.54.117.215
parkingpage.namecheap.com. 29   IN  A   198.54.117.216
parkingpage.namecheap.com. 29   IN  A   198.54.117.212

→ dig www.ubbytech.com
www.ubbytech.com.   59  IN  CNAME   www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com.
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   54.221.218.81
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   54.235.135.158
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   54.243.85.55
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   75.101.145.225
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   54.243.154.49
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   107.21.206.81
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   54.243.91.166
www.ubbytech.com.herokudns.com. 59 IN   A   54.235.212.238
```

so the first response returns a namecheap address which the second returns a herokudns.com address. This usually means you've misconfigured the DNS servers for your domain. Looking at the WhoIs data for your app I can see

```
Name Server: dns1.registrar-servers.com 
Name Server: dns2.registrar-servers.com
```

which looks ok - that leads me to think that one of those servers has the new record and the other is returning the old one...either way, it's a DNS issue and a question for namecheap.

Comment: Ok I will definitely give them a call and ask them about this. Thanks a bunch!